# Convert ES6 array of string to an array of object with the same key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I convert this array of fruits,

> ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Peach']

to an array of object with the same key,

`[{
  name: 'Apple',
},{
  name: 'Banana',
},{
  name: 'Orange'
},{
  name: 'Peach'
}]`

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `array#map` with Object shorthand property.

```js
let data = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Peach'],
    result = data.map(name => ({name}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.